# YII Pluggin for Net Beans

Tags: php, plugins, netbeans, yii

Can you please let me know where do I get YII Framework plugin for Netbeans? I tried to search but I couldn't find.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is why do you need a plugin? 
Just include Yii framework path in your project include path and all your functions will be part of autocomplete. 
I use Yii with netbeans all the time and never felt the need for one. However there is another IDE, codelobster, who recently launched a plugin for yii, you might check it out but it is not as good as netbeans for advanced users, however good enough for basic usage so you might be interested.

Answer (score 1):

Also for PDT there is plugin adding yii framework support. At the moment functionality is limited to creating new yii-powered project and some useful navigation (controller/action -> view, view -> view (partial render), widget->widgetClass, and some others.
More information you can find at [yiiclipse](http://yiiclipse.maziarz.org) home page.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one currently.  That's why you couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

actually it is available here is the link

http://www.yiiframework.com/news/69/yii-plugin-for-netbeans/